# In Oracle VirtualBox (VM) issue with full screen

Tags: virtualization

In VM  the control option to go to fullscreen is right hand CTL and f.
But that doesn't make the VM go to full screen. all it does is  create a blackened full screen area around the actual VM window.  I did a screen cast of the event and did a screen shot if it (infra).
What, if anything, might I be doing wrong?

This is what I get after enlarging it and  using the key strokes to go fullscreen
[image: fullscreen]

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions?

Answer (score 0):

"Have you installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions? –
steeldriver"

Didn't know what that was.
I just installed it  using the instructions I found on itsfoss. however the interface  is a little different from theirs.
I got it to scale to 200% which is a huge improvement.